# unable to get value of the property 'length' object is null or undefined jquery with a requiredfield validator

Tags: jquery, .net

I have the following code in .net

```
<asp:TextBox ID="txtdaStartDate" runat="server"
   ValidationGroup="DA" Columns="10"></asp:TextBox>
                &nbsp;<asp:RequiredFieldValidator ID="txtreqdaStartDate"
                   runat="server"  Enabled="false"
                    ControlToValidate="txtdaStartDate"
                    Text="Start Date is required" 
                    ValidationGroup="DA" 
                    ForeColor="Red"
                    Display="Dynamic"></asp:RequiredFieldValidator>
```

when I select the calendar control on the web page, it display a script error.
unable to get value of the property 'length' object is null or undefined

Comment: Can you show us your HTML and JavaScript code?

Answer (score 1):

Here's the fix (add an empty onSelect handler):

```
$("#DateTextBoxId").datepicker({ onSelect: function() {} });
```